# \bibliographystyle{plain} and \citet

Tags: bibtex

I want to use `\citet` since it is convenient (I do not type the author's name myself).
But I found the conference ask to use `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and this conference likes to number the references.

So I have to make a citation, say `\cite`

```
\cite{a}
```

= someone et al. [1].

Actually, I use `\bibliographystyle{achemso}`. And it produce what I want. But the reference do not have the name of the paper. E.g.

> [2]Esser, E.; Zhang, X.; Chan, T. F. SIAM J. Img. Sci. 2010, 3, 1015–1046.

With the comment of Mico, I solve this problem. But still several titles are missing.
E.g.

```
 @INPROCEEDINGS{conf/nips/SmolaVL07,
  author = {Smola, Alex J. and Vishwanathan, S. V. N. and Le, Quoc V.},
  title = {Bundle Methods for Machine Learning.},
  booktitle = {NIPS},
  year = {2007},
  editor = {Platt, John C. and Koller, Daphne and Singer, Yoram and Roweis, Sam
    T.},
  publisher = {MIT Press},
  added-at = {2011-11-24T00:51:13.000+0100},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2d05d5e55475c03831974396e2c0d88bf/wkotl},
  crossref = {conf/nips/2007},
  description = {dblp},
  ee = {http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips20/NIPS2007_0470.pdf},
  interhash = {bc8df8615544df575dc9d183ba73b809},
  intrahash = {d05d5e55475c03831974396e2c0d88bf},
  keywords = {TO-READ optimization},
  timestamp = {2011-11-24T00:51:13.000+0100},
  url = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/nips/nips2007.html#SmolaVL07}
}
```

This shows like

> [16] Smola, A. J., Vishwanathan, S. V. N., & Le, Q. V. 2007, in NIPS, ed. J. C. Platt, D. Koller, 221 222 Y. Singer, & S. T. Roweis (MIT Press)

I use answer to write a little sample. But it does solve the problem of citation.

```
\documentclass[review]{OAGM}
%% For the accepted, final version, set this to the correct value:
%%\OAGMarXiv{0000.0000}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{ulem}
 \usepackage{float} % fix the table
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsopn}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{breqn} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{achemso} 
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle}
\begin{filecontents*}{\klkl.bib}
% This file was created with JabRef 2.9.2.
% Encoding: UTF8

@INPROCEEDINGS{conf/icml/AvronKKS12,
  author = {Avron, Haim and Kale, Satyen and Kasiviswanathan, Shiva Prasad and
    Sindhwani, Vikas},
  title = {Efficient and Practical Stochastic Subgradient Descent for Nuclear
    Norm Regularization.},
  booktitle = {ICML},
  year = {2012},
  publisher = {icml.cc / Omnipress},
  added-at = {2013-01-25T00:00:00.000+0100},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2b9ed7719ec246e3629d4b41b5515c7f9/dblp},
  crossref = {conf/icml/2012},
  ee = {http://icml.cc/discuss/2012/617.html},
  interhash = {afa43f2081a8e76fd4ceeca426a7dc66},
  intrahash = {b9ed7719ec246e3629d4b41b5515c7f9},
  keywords = {dblp},
  timestamp = {2013-01-25T00:00:00.000+0100},
  url = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/icml/icml2012.html#AvronKKS12}
}


\end{filecontents*}






%\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{Equation \eqref{#1}}}
\let\originaleqref=\eqref
\renewcommand{\eqref}{Equation~\originaleqref}

\newcommand{\dataset}{{\cal D}}
\newcommand{\fracpartial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial  #2}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\newarg}{arg} 
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}                  % for absolute value
\newcommand{\avg}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}           % for average
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}            % for norm
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}            % for {}
\newcommand{\sbra}[1]{\left[ #1 \right]}            % for []
\newcommand{\lbra}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}            % for ()
\newcommand{\reffig}[1]{Figure \ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\d}[2]{\dfrac{\mathrm{d} #1}{\mathrm{d} #2}}       % for derivatives
\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}            % for partial derivatives
\let\underdot=\d                             % rename builtin command \d{} to \underdot{}
\title{Margin?}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Today is 3/14/2014.
 \end{abstract}
\newpage
Here is a new page\cite{conf/icml/AvronKKS12}.
\bibliography{\klkl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico, Thank you for your comment. I use \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}.

Comment: @Mico, It works. But it makes the wrong order.[10] Ahookhosh, M. 2014, unpublished manuscript 133
134 [6] Beck, A., & Teboulle, M. 2009, A Fast Iterative Shrinkage-Thresholding Algorithm for Linear Inverse 134
135 Problems, SIAM J. Img. Sci., 2, 183                                            It is not [1] followed by [2]..

Comment: Please edit your posting to highlight *all* the requirements you have -- and maybe also remove some of the material you mention but aren't asking to be fixed.

Comment: @Mico, thank you for your comment. I need to learn how to highlight   since I did not use before.

Comment: @Adam, Thank you for your editing. I learn a lot.

Comment: @Vivian As you are using `achemso`, are you using the companion package? If so, all that is needed to add titles is `\setkeys{acs}{usetitle}`, then running LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX/LaTeX.

Comment: @JosephWright, thank you. I did not use \usepackage{companion}.

Comment: @Vivian Not `\usepackage{companion}`, `\usepackage{achemso}`, _i.e._ the _companion to the `achemso` BibTeX style_.

Comment: @Mico Note that editing the `achemso` style is a bad idea here as it's set up to have flexibility in printing of titles and so doesn't have a simple piece of code to alter.

Comment: @JosephWright - Thanks for this pointer. I will delete my earlier comment.

Comment: @JosephWright, Thank you for your comment. I do not use `\usepackage{achemso}`. I use the method of Mico.

Comment: @JosephWright, I try to use your method since Mico's method results missing title. So in `cls`, I use `\bibliographystyle{plain}`. In `tex`, I use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and `\usepackage{achemso} \setkeys{acs}{usetitle = true} `. But in this case, there is a error, `Option clash for package natbib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `achemso` BibTeX style is set up to allow special citations to pass style settings from LaTeX. This can be used automatically using the `achemso` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle}

% This is just for demo purposes
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Rauchfuss2008,
  Title                    = 
    {Aza- and Oxadithiolates Are Probable Proton Relays in Functional Models for the [FeFe]-Hydrogenases},
  Author                   = {Barton, Bryan E. and Olsen, Matthew T. and Rauchfuss, Thomas B.},
  Journal                  = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  Year                     = {2008},
  Number                   = {50},
  Pages                    = {16834-16835},
  Volume                   = {130},
  Doi                      = {10.1021/ja8057666},
  Timestamp                = {2009.09.21}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Some text \citet{Rauchfuss2008}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the package automatically loads the `natbib` package and does some other settings changes: these are all described in the manual.

If you want to do everything 'by hand' then you can create the control citation yourself. A suitable set up would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

% This is needed to pass control data to the BibTeX style
% Once the .bib file is created, you can just edit it directly
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-control.bib}
@Control{achemso-control,
  ctrl-article-title  = "yes",
  ctrl-chapter-title  = "no",
  ctrl-etal-number    = "15",
  ctrl-etal-firstonly = "yes",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\AtBeginDocument{\nocite{achemso-control}}

% This is just for demo purposes
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Rauchfuss2008,
  Title                    = 
    {Aza- and Oxadithiolates Are Probable Proton Relays in Functional Models for the [FeFe]-Hydrogenases},
  Author                   = {Barton, Bryan E. and Olsen, Matthew T. and Rauchfuss, Thomas B.},
  Journal                  = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  Year                     = {2008},
  Number                   = {50},
  Pages                    = {16834-16835},
  Volume                   = {130},
  Doi                      = {10.1021/ja8057666},
  Timestamp                = {2009.09.21}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

Some text \citet{Rauchfuss2008}

\bibliography{\jobname,\jobname-control}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}

\end{document}
```

Notice here the need for a `\nocite` and the addition of a second database to the `\bibliography` line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I use `\bibliography{\jobname}`, why I need to explicitly write `\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-control.bib}
@Control{achemso-control,
  ctrl-article-title  = "yes",
  ctrl-chapter-title  = "no",
  ctrl-etal-number    = "15",
  ctrl-etal-firstonly = "yes",
}` to lead a quite long file .

Comment: I use method one. But it does not work. \setkeys{acs}{usetitle} or \setkeys{acs}{articletitle}? And Should I use `\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}` or `\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}`? I have these two question because there are errors.

Comment: @Vivian The reason for having the long-ish file for the 'all manual' version is that you need to create a special `.bib` file entry. This can be done by hand or simply placed in a normal `.bib` file, but done in the way I have here it is certain to be available as it's bundled up as part of the `.tex` file.

Comment: @Vivian You can call the 'control' `.bib` file anything you like as long as the file name is the same as the one you add to the `\bibliography` line. The option used to be called `usetitle` but got renamed to `articletitle`: the old name still works but for new code please use the new name.

Comment: @Vivian I'm not quite sure what you mean: perhaps you want to alter the citation style? If so, use `\setcitestyle` (described in the `natbib` manual).

Comment: ,thank you for your comment. I just means e.g. `[2]` appears on the top right corner of text.